# request.parameter(String) returns null when called from jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jsp

I am developing web application.
I am sending json string from one page to another.
I have used jquery to send the post data.
In the target page I want to retrieve the same data.
But I am getting the `null` value there.

my page which posts json string to page is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.post("./ProfileUser.jsp",{jsonData:jsonstr});
    $(location).attr('href',"./ProfileUser.jsp");
});
```

And in the page `ProfileUser.jsp`

```
<%
String jsonData = request.getParameter("jsonData");
String mobile;
if(jsonData == null)  mobile = "something went wrong";
else {
    JSONObject j  =new JSONObject(jsonData);
    mobile = j.getString("mobile");
}
%>
```

I am getting output as `Something went wrong` which should be mobile number from the database.
How should I get the json data in jsp?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**First** you need to add the `third parameter` as json in [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post)
 like,

```
$.post("./ProfileUser.jsp",{jsonData:jsonstr},'json');
```

**Secondly,** in **JSP** try it like,

```
JSONObject json      = new JSONObject();
if(!jsonData) {
   json.put("mobile", "111111");
}
else{
   //something;
}
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here what is the significance of response.* after the is else . I want to get data from json string in else block

Comment: What is `request` parameter` here, `response` is same like `request parameter`=> `HttpServletResponse Object`

Comment: Now test the above answer I've made changes in it.

Comment: I want ouput as some mobile number as 9922xxxx but i am getting 11111/"something went wrong" ,cause i am not getting json string from jquery

Comment: Check by using `console` what goes to the `server`?